# urxvt not loading the icons for lf filemanager

Tags: linux, rxvt, bspwm

I am using urxvt

Below is my .Xresources file

```
URxvt*buffered: false
URxvt.font: xft:monospace:size=15,xft:DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font:size=10
URxvt*letterSpace:-1
URxvt.scrollBar: false

URxvt*background:                     #151718
URxvt*foreground:                     #d6d6d6

URxvt*cursorColor:                    #d6d6d6

URxvt*highlightColor:                 #3B758C
URxvt*highlightTextColor:             #43a5d5

URxvt*color0:                         #151718
URxvt*color1:                         #Cd3f45
URxvt*color2:                         #9fca56
URxvt*color3:                         #e6cd69
URxvt*color4:                         #55b5db
URxvt*color5:                         #a074c4
URxvt*color6:                         #55dbbe
URxvt*color7:                         #d6d6d6
URxvt*color8:                         #41535B
URxvt*color9:                         #Cd3f45
URxvt*color10:                        #9fca56
URxvt*color11:                        #e6cd69
URxvt*color12:                        #55b5db
URxvt*color13:                        #a074c4
URxvt*color14:                        #55dbbe
URxvt*color15:                        #ffffff

! 256 color space
URxvt*color16:                        #db7b55
URxvt*color17:                        #8a553f
URxvt*color18:                        #8ec43d
URxvt*color19:                        #3B758C
URxvt*color20:                        #43a5d5
URxvt*color21:                        #eeeeee


!! Extensions
URxvt.perl-ext-common: resize-font,url-select,clipboard

!! extension settings
URxvt.keysym.C-Down:  resize-font:smaller
URxvt.keysym.C-Up:    resize-font:bigger

URxvt.keysym.M-u: perl:url-select:select_next
URxvt.url-select.launcher: /usr/bin/xdg-open
URxvt.url-select.underline: true

URxvt.clipboard.autocopy: true
URxvt.keysym.C-c: perl:clipboard:copy
URxvt.keysym.C-v: perl:clipboard:paste
```

I have lf file manager installed in  my machine with icons enabled in 
~/.config/lf/lfrc file as shown below

set icons true

After that if i open the lf file manager in urxvt in place of icon i have a box symbol appearing and icons are not loaded properly

if i run

```
 fc-match "DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font"
```

i am able to is the font listed

```
DejaVu Sans Mono Nerd Font Complete.ttf: "DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font
```

This issue i am facing only in urxvt. But if i open lf file manager in st terminal able to see the icon displayed properly.

Answer (score 0):

After searching little more time. I got a link which solved my issue.

https://github.com/gokcehan/lf/wiki/Icons

But still i did not know how it worked in st terminal . Very much confused.